# how to convert using statement in C#?

Tags: asp.net

i am working on asp.net and i wnt to convert following statement in to the c#

```
Using response As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        st = reader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using
```

if any one knows it please tell me.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Well, a literal translation would be:

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    st = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

However, if the response *isn't* an `HttpWebResponse` that will still fail - just with a `NullReferenceException`. I'd prefer to cast:

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    st = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Or to be ultra careful that the response will be cleaned up even if it isn't a web response:

```
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) response;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
    st = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

... but `WebResponse` already contains `GetResponseStream`, so there's no need to cast to `HttpWebResponse` in the first place, to be honest.

Answer (score 4):

The C# will be something like this:

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    st = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

And If I can recognize the code, I think that request.GetResponse() will always be a HttpWebResponse, so you can cast directly as opposed to `request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse` which will return null if the response is not a `HttpWebResponse`.

Answer (score 3):

```
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    st = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most direct conversion of `TryCast` from VB.NET is the `as` operator in C#. Doing a direct cast will cause an Exception to be thrown rather than `response` being null:

```
using(HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    st = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Something like this:

```
using(HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
     //Your code here...
}
```

Comment: you really shouldn't be putting `TrySomething` in a using statement opener.